# How to convert 24hr into milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a function that will convert the 24hr into milliseconds.

e.g `14:00` into milliseconds?

Comment: This is a bit like asking "how to multiply 100 by 1000"? Seriously, this is *basic* math, this is not even a programming question.

Comment: He's asking for how to convert the format hh:mm to milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
var hours = "14:00";
var array = hours.split(":"); //splits into two 1. hours 2. minutes
var milliSec = array[0]*60*60*1000 + array[1]*60*1000; //result - 50400000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `split` it and use `parseInt`:

```
var str = '14:00';
var strSplit = str.split(':');
var milliseconds = ((parseInt(strSplit[0], 10) * 3600) + parseInt(strSplit[1], 10) * 60) * 1000;
console.log(milliseconds); //50400000
```

Comment: I am curious why it was down voted.

Comment: @akonsu Seeing as all answers in this thread are downvoted my guess is that someone was petty and thought "since OP didn't do any research, I'm going to downvote all the answers for even answering, even though their answer was correct". If it made them feel any better, then that's great for that person. :-)

Comment: +1 ..  absolutely.. works great